# What's the translation of “marginable security" in French?

Tags: traduction, adjectifs, finance

Marginable securities [refer to](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/marginable.asp):

> stocks, bonds, futures or other securities capable of being traded on margin. Securities traded on margin, paid for by a loan, are facilitated through a brokerage or other financial institution that lends the money for these trades.

What's the translation of “marginable security" in French?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That can be:

> *Titre marginable*

> *Et j'oubliais, dans un compte marge ce qui peu faire mal c'est si tu as un **titre marginable** à 70% et que du jour au lendemain il baisse à 50%.  Ca arrive pas avec des grosses entreprises avec du volume cotées à plus de 5$ (genre Couche-Tard).  Mais avec BMTC ou MEQ ou des plus petites entreprises avec un faible volume ça m'est déjà arrivé d'avoir un rappel de marge imprévu pour cette raison.*

http://forum.entrepreneurboursier.com/discussion/304/gestionnaires-quebecois/p2

Otherwise, you can use this:

> *Titre disponible en achat sur marge* or *achat à découvert*.

Answer (score 3):

Il s'agit évidemment d'une [valeur mobilière](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2071671) et il vaut mieux employer *marginable securities* au pluriel si on veut obtenir quoi que ce soit de Google (*titres sur marge*). J'ai regardé les articles sur Investopedia ([1](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/marginable.asp), [2](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/non_marginable_securities.asp)) et après un bref survol de quelques sites canadiens j'ai identifié :

> Titre [admissible](https://www6.royalbank.com/fr/di/reference/article/eligible-securities-and-applicable-margin/imt5qhh6) à [une](https://www.bmo.com/placements-autogeres/popups/calcul-des-marges)/[la marge](https://nouveausite.ocrcvm.ca/rules/4000/4316-valeur-de-pret-nette-et-valeur-marchande-des-titres-dans-les-comptes-de-clients#3925188384-4259091021)/aux fins de marge/[pour
> fins de marge](https://www.m-x.ca/f_circulaires_fr/018-06_fr.pdf).
>  [Titre pouvant être utilisé à des fins d'avance
> sur marge.](https://www.disnat.com/plateformes-et-frais/tarification#collapse-tab-07)
>  [Titre admissible à une marge/couverture
> réduite](https://www.ocrcvm.ca/documents/2020/fbc540af-560a-45ed-b448-07db196e40fe_fr.pdf). [un [cas particulier](http://forum.entrepreneurboursier.com/discussion/1224/critere-de-marge-reduite-dun-titre-et-changement-dans-la-liste), en surcroît de l'admissibilité à une marge moins
> favorable.]
>  Titre dont l'achat peut être fait à crédit. [[plus
> généralement](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=502584)]

Il n'y a rien d'intrinsèque au titre dans la qualification et il s'agit purement de financement et d'analyse du risque en contexte d'un [*compte sur marge*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8378576).